# Unlock Azure VM Local Administrator Password

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, password-recovery

I have been looking at [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/24264/how-do-i-recover-reset-the-admin-password-of-a-virtual-pc-instance) question and most of it makes sense but a lot of it is going over my head. I'm a software developer and my I.T Admin' has left leaving me with hard job of unlocking a virtual machine we need to recover.

I would like to recover the VM and use it again. The research link I was reading above, suggests it is do-able but I need this breaking down for me as I am getting lost at the booting from a vm and running specialist software on it.

Apologies for the spoon feed me approach, but I have spent the better part of a weekend trying to do this via powershell but as an early adopter of azure, the vm in question does not have the azure vm agent installed on it which means 95% of all help on the web on this matter is instantly ruled out. I tried resetting the password from the portal but that does not work either.

All i have is the vhd of the os disk downloaded of the vm I want to save. Can you guys help me recover the admin password of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a VM using the vhd you downloaded as the only disc.

2) In the profile for the virtual machine find the virtual cd/dvd drive and pick use iso image.

3) Select your iso for your recovery tool. Hirensbootcd comes as an iso and has a good tool for recovering the password.

4) Start virtual machine and press a key to boot from cd.

5) Follow onscreen options to reset administrator password.

The steps are the same regardless of what bootable iso you use. This is the simplest method. Once this is complete you can choose to put it back up to azure.

Comment: Cool. What software could i use to create the VM? VirtualPC?

Comment: In its current format the vhd(x) would work with hyper-v, I think you'd have to convert for use with vm or virtualpc

Comment: cool, do the above instructions work as expected with hyper-v?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/196158/how-to-create-and-run-virtual-machines-with-hyper-v/

Comment: Yes they do, and following that article will get you to the right place

Comment: I'm, so far everything you have told me has worked so far. so thank you. I'm at the stage with 'Hirensbootcd' and i don't think it can unlock windows server 2012 r2 local administrator accounts.

Comment: It can, I've done it plenty of times.... Try following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zxHrYAKObqw

Comment: Cheers, I will try that tonight, when i get home and i will get back to you. It shouldn't take me long to try it - everything is already set-up. = )